# How to use multiple content types in a "Calendar" View sorting by the field type of "Date"?

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

I am using a module called "[Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar)" that puts a calendar on the sidebar, and allows you to add events using a cck, which will be displayed on the calendar so that you can click the date, and it will bring you to the event (along with any other event that day.) the problem is, that i don't want to have to create all new content using the cck that was part of the Calendar module. when installing the module, it added a field type called "Date", which is what the calendar events are sorted by. this allowed me to add other cck events that had that field, into the calendar. The problem is, that it puts in onto the wrong date. instead of putting it onto the date that it is set at, it is put onto the date that it was created. is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the calendar view's Contextual Filter (Under "Advanced") to use the new date field, instead of the post date.

[image]

Comment: I am looking in that, but I don't see any of the (field_date) options. the only options I see are: 1. Content: Last comment timae 2. Content: Post date 3. Content: Updated date 4. User: Created date 5. User: Last access 6. User: Last login

Comment: Have you added your own date field to the content type?

Comment: yes, I added the "date" field type to several content types.

Comment: I recall that I had this issue where my date fields were not showing up. See http://drupal.org/node/1181196 for follow up. Basically it says, "Make sure you have the very latest dev code for Date, Calendar (if you use it), Views, and CTools. That means the -dev versions of everything."

Comment: I have dev on everything except views, which is alpha-3. is there  way to change that in which I won't have uninstall and reinstall views, so that I don't loose all of the views that I have already created?

Comment: You shouldn't have to uninstall views to update to the latest dev.

Comment: well, i'm using an FTP server, and in order to install it, I would have to upload the dev version to the same folder, which would over-write the one that I currently have on there.

Comment: Overwriting the modules file structure does not overwrite your views. They are stored in the Database. Backup up your site, delete the Alpha version, upload the dev version, run update.php. Your views will still be there and then you should see your date field(s).

Comment: ok, so I got the new views, and I changed "updated date" to date(s)(field_date), but it didn't change my calendar at all. is there anything else I need to do? do I need to add anything to the Fields in the veiw? do I need a filter criteria?

Comment: See http://drupaltherapy.com/date_d7 for a step by step walkthrough to see if you missed any steps. Or take a look of an export of my view http://drupalbin.com/19208