# Calendar with multiple content types on multiple field types

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm hoping to set up a calendar using date + calendar. I have 2 content types, one of which specifically has a date field, the other of which I want to display on the calendar using the published date. How could I go about doing this? I can get the first content to display under two different dates, one for published date and the other for its date field, but obviously this is not the desired behavior.

The following issue kind-of comes close, but not quite: [How to use multiple content types in a "Calendar" View sorting by the field type of "Date"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/how-to-use-multiple-content-types-in-a-calendar-view-sorting-by-the-field-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to get Views to add the 2nd content type (and only the 2nd content type) in this way, at least not through the Views UI. You could do this by programmatically altering the view's query or something like that, but it would be no fun.

I would recycle the "date" field from content type a into content type b and set the default value = now; that way when a new node is created it will have that value by default.

Comment: I thought about doing this. However, future plans are for content type b to be published at a later date from the creation date (which I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing).

Comment: You could use Rules to schedule the publishing of the node, and could also update your "date" field at the same time. That's all up to how you want to handle the publishing though.