# Can 1 FullCalendar show dates from more than one content type?

Tags: 7, datetime, javascript

I want to show "dates" and "Board Meetings" on my FullCalendar.  How?

Background info:
In D7 I created a Calendar using the wizard, which shows titles and dates/times of events that I create using a content type "Date" that the wizard created.  Works great.  But then I added another content type "Board Meeting" with a date field, the Board meetings only show up on the preview, not on the calendar month view itself.  How to get them to show on the calendar?

Dave N

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer before I even finished posting this.  Thanks to those "Similar Questions" over there on the right...

I got my answer from [How to use multiple content types in a "Calendar" View sorting by the field type of "Date"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/how-to-use-multiple-content-types-in-a-calendar-view-sorting-by-the-field-type)